# Lambda cannot find sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, aws-lambda, sklearn-pandas

This seems to be a common question, but most often the answer is "make sure you zip from *within* the folder".  I do not think that is my problem.

I am following [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/data-science-for-startups-model-services-2facf2dde81d).  I can do the first part as described, setting up an API to echo some text.

For the second part, I set up my folder exactly as described.  In an ec2, I create a new folder, install the three libraries into it, build the pkl and `logit.py`.  And then, *within the folder*, ZIP it all.  This is what it looks like.

[image]

Note: `sklearn` exists!

In a fresh lambda, I tell it to point to s3 and load my ZIP (that I've put there).  I swap the handler to `logit.lambda_handler`.

But inevitably, my error tells me that `sklearn` is not present.  Error message:

```
Unable to import module 'logit': No module named 'sklearn'
```

Why is it not picking up the module?